# Issue with NULL values in creating a view in sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a SQL View over a table with different values in it. I am trying to combine two columns in a table to be displayed in a single column of a view separated by a '/'.

For Example I have two columns in a table named `In` and `inVolume` with values for 'In' being
 `1,2,NULL`

and for 'inVolume ' being

`NULL, 100, 200`

and the results I was expecting are  `1/(NULL or Empty)`,  `2/100, (NULL or Empty)/200` but when I created the view and ran it the results were *`(NULL or Empty), 2/100, (NULL or Empty)`*. The issue being it is making the column in view as NULL if any of the columns In or inVolume in the table are NULL.

I created the following view

**SQL View**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Result]
AS

with CTE as(
SELECT distinct
   CC.Product,
   CC.Term,   
   CC.TermID,
   iCC.In,
   iCC.Out,
   iCC.inVolume,
   iCC.outVolume

   FROM Cust CC
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 3
                In,
                Out, 
               inVolume,
                outVolume

             FROM Cust iCC
             WHERE CC.Term = iCC.Term and CC.Product = iCC.Product
             ORDER BY iCC.In DESC, iCC.Out ASC) iCC)
             select Product, Term, cast(inVolume as varchar(99)) + '/' + cast(In as varchar(99)) as value, inlabel as label from CTE 
             union
             select Product, Term, cast(Out as varchar(99)) + '/' + cast(outVolume as varchar(99)), outlabel from CTE 

GO
```

Any better way to deal with this?

Comment: `ISNULL(cast(In as varchar(99)), '(NULL OR EMPTY)')`?

Comment: NULL will absorb any other value you concatenate with, the same way multiplying any number by 0 will always return 0. Use ISNULL to replace null values by empty string or a "NULL" string as suggested by Daniel E.

Comment: You'll need to use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
cast(outVolume as varchar(99))
```

Whit this:

```
cast((CASE WHEN outVolume IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE outVolume END) as varchar(99))
```

On every field. Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
cast(inVolume as varchar(99)) + '/' + cast(In as varchar(99))`
```

with

```
cast(inVolume as varchar(99)) + '/' 
+ ISNULL(cast(In as varchar(99)), '(NULL OR EMPTY)')`
```

and

```
cast(Out as varchar(99)) + '/' + cast(outVolume as varchar(99))`
```

with

```
cast(Out as varchar(99)) + '/' 
+ ISNULL(cast(outVolume as varchar(99)), '(NULL OR EMPTY)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `IsNull` to enable nullable-column concatentation

```
select Product, Term, 
IsNull(inVolume, '(NULL OR EMPTY)', cast(inVolume as varchar(99))) + '/' + 
IsNull(In, '(NULL OR EMPTY)', cast(In as varchar(99))) as value, 
inlabel as label from CTE 

UNION

select Product, Term, 
IsNull(Out, '(NULL OR EMPTY)', cast(Out as varchar(99))) + '/' + 
IsNull(outVolume, '(NULL OR EMPTY)', cast(outVolume as varchar(99))), 
outlabel from CTE
```